# Accessing values of a tuple inside a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am a beginner. I have a question that how we can access values of tuple inside a list. Example

```
def point_function():
    my_list=[]
    num=int(input("Dear User, How many points you want to enter: "))
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        print(f"Please input the coordinates of the point {i}")
        x=float(input("Please enter x-coordinate of the point: "))
        y=float(input("Please enter y-coordinate of the point: "))
        my_tuple=(x,y)
        my_list.append(my_tuple)
    print(my_list)                    

point_function()
```

This function will create a list of tuples with stored point coordinates, Now if I want to access them and find the distance between all the points. The distance is covered between the point and the point following it. How will I do that?

I tried to search it, but I didn't get any suitable answer.
Advance thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think you have accepted the wrong (and unformatted) answer (it only _prints_ the first element, the x-coordinate from your list of x and y coordinates, which is entirely wrong). Please don't accept wrong answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
for tup in my_list:
    x, y = tup # assuming there two values inside the tuple to unpack
    print(x, y)
    print(tup[0], tup[1]) # in case you want to access with indexing
```

To subtract first tuple from second tuple inside your list:

```
x_diff = my_list[0][0] - my_list[1][0]
y_diff = my_list[0][1] - my_list[1][1]
```

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again, as mentioned above in my question to calculate the distance between points, I have to subtract the first value of the first tuple with the first value of the second tuple and the same goes for the second value. What should be done to subtract them ?

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple_list = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
first_element = []

for i in tuple_list:
   first_element.append(i[0])

print(first_element)
```

**output**:

```
'a', 'c'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change print(my_list) to return my_list
In the main code block assgine your def function (points = point_function()), then you can print out the result. You can sort out the x and y values with a for loop. I do not know the formula for figuring distances between points but I think you can manage that part out.